# Q: Access asp:TextBox value without rendering it in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, security

I've created an asp:TextBox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTheBestID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Hello!" />
```

I am trying to access the text value using JQuery like below, but the object it returns is not defined unless Visible="true" is in place instead. I think this makes sense to me, because since it is not in the source it cannot be found.

```
    function doSomethingInJS() {
        var myVal = $("#<%= tbTheBestID.ClientID%>").val();
    }
```

I am looking for a way to access a variable I declare on the server side from JQuery without having it visible in the source, because that data may be sensitive and I don't want users to have access to it.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `visible="false"` will prevent it from rendering.  What you need to do is prevent it from displaying by using a CSS class or `display: none;`.

Change your code to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTheBestID" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" Text="Hello!" />
```

And add to your CSS (note, many frameworks may already have a .hidden class):

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, this will be available in the source, including any value.

Because jQuery runs on the client side, it can only access information it has been sent (therefore it must be in the page to be seen by the page).

If it is sensitive information, perhaps consider a webservice to feed an `$.ajax` call.  Note, that this does not make the data safe, but it minimises the exposure time.

Comment: Thanks for the response; that helped me understand what was going on. I'm going to have to move that bit to the code behind instead to keep the info from being visible in the source. :p

Comment: Unfortunately, one can be forgiven for assuming that anything in javascript/jQuery cannot be made safe from malicious (or just nosey) users.  Best keep anything truly sensitive in the code-behind.